# Are there search algorithms that are competitive against (gradient based) optimization routines for continuous problems?

Tags: reference-request, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, teaching, operations-research

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function for which we want to minimize. We may arbitrarily impose good conditions for $f$, such as Lipschitzness, smoothness, convexity, etc.

The intuitive way, if you were to teach about minimizing such a function in a first-course on optimization, would be **search**, rather than things like gradient descent because that takes a bit more work to motivate the concept of a gradient, etc.

Does there exist results that either show that no "search algorithm" can be competitive with optimization routine (particularly those that are gradient based), or that search algorithms are suboptimal as compared to gradient based algorithms, or that there exist search algorithms such that for some classes of problem it is better than any gradient based method, or perhaps they are equivalent in some sense.

By search algorithm, I refer to that class of algorithms where you either randomly or deterministic test points in some regions until exhaustion. One example is bisection methods for 1D functions, but I am thinking more generically.

Comment: First: this is a loaded question, since comparing zero-order and first-order (just like first-order and second-order) methods is apples to oranges if you don't have a structured problem where you can fairly compare gradient evaluation (or Newton-step computation) to function evaluation. If you just count iterations, zero-order methods are, unsurprisingly, suboptimal; see, e.g., https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/DucZero15.pdf and the references therein.

Comment: (Note that this comment is biased by my background in infinite-dimensional optimization, so I don't consider the dimension $n$ as a fixed parameter that may safely be absorbed into a constant.)

Comment: And as an aside, after presenting optimality conditions (as a natural answer to the question "how can you check whether a point is a minimizer without comparing to _all_ other feasible points, which is clearly infeasible"), the gradient method is fairly straightforward to motivate as an algorithm for computing such points.

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks, that's already lots of food for thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be shown. What is needed is a fair ground for comparison of different algorithms and I can recommend the book "Introductory Lectures on Convex Optimization - A Basic Course" by Yurii Nesterov. There you'll find a hands-on introduction to complexity theory for continuous problems.

(A side note: Gradient descent is inherently a search method. The gradient just tells you in which direction to look...)